# PHPUnit tests running too quickly, making no difference in MySQL timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, phpunit

I have a PHP class that create a line with a CURRENT_TIMESTAMPS in a MySQL database when I create a new instance of it. This timestamp is then used to sort theses records (and primarily getting the last one).

In this precise case, the timestamp is the automatically generated `created_at` column of an Eloquent (Laravel) model. If possible I'd like a solution that is not Laravel-specific given I could encounter the same problem with other projects.

I had written tests for this class on another PC and everything was working fine, the resulting oder was always correct.

Now I copied this project on my other PC that has an SSD and that is (but not much) more powerful than the other. And now, all my tests fail, because all records end up having the exact same timestamp.

In production it would **not** be a an issue if two records had the same timestamps (which is very unlikely), but that's not the situation I try to replicate in my test.

To quickly address the issue without digging in the code, I added some sleep(1) functions before instantiating a new object.

But now my question is, what is the best way to deal with that ?

Here are a few possibilities I thought of, but I'm not sure which one is the best:

- Hard-coding the dates in the tests: no risk of failure, but my objects currently offer no way to define a date manually. I would need to add methods for that, and they won't be used for anything else.
- Empty the database before doing the next operation. The problem there is that for certain tests I need to insert two objects one after the other, so it wouldn't solve all the problems
- Make the code wait. But it sounds very stupid to me, because I lose all the benefits of having a powerful machine. And of course it takes much more time to run the tests
- Manipulating the system or the database current time. I have no idea of what horrible things could happen if I try that ! Maybe it is possible to isolate a process that do that without impacting anything else on the PC ?

So which method do you recommend ? Is there a better one ?

More system informations: All my dev machines are running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5. My current project is using the Laravel 4 framework and phpunit for the tests

### Additional informations

I'd like to add there what I said in the comments below.
Ideally my test should do its assertions with dates that are spaced by many hours, but for the moment I relied on the fact that two records had at least one second difference, which is no more the case with this other PC config.

And, additional informations, in production, the older records get normally deleted before a new one is inserted or the db queried (say, 90% of the time) so even if two were created quickly, there would be a chance that one is removed before I do my logic on the database. But for my test, I need to have at least two records in database, spaced by some time, which is not important but greater than zero.

Comment: Smells like a design failure... Do you really need to relay on a timestamp to get the last record? Imho this will fail at some point. How about switching to a pk with an auto incremented value?

Comment: @aichingm I agree with you, but my problem here is how to "simulate" the missing time between two records. What I'm testing here would normally be spaced by many hours in production, but I need a test that run in seconds.

Comment: @aichingm And for me an auto-increment field should not be trusted for sorting. What if two synced servers use different incrementing starts, like 1 for the first and 10000 for the second one ? I could add another field in the db but again, this case (with identical times) is deliberately not treated in my application

Comment: does the timestamp field has a `UNIQUE` constraint? And what type of error handling do you use?

Comment: you can try current time for first insert and then increment that time stamp with some constant number , like $time = time()+10 , for all other insertions

Comment: @aichingm no there are no UNIQUE constraint, and no error handling for duplicates, given it's a legitimate situation for my app (but not the one I try to test)

Comment: @Deep123 yes it falls under the first possibility of my list. The thing is that if I do that I need to permit the used to manually set a time when using my class, which I would prefer not to do. (But for now it sounds the safer and easier method to achieve my goal)

Comment: For code testing, you could mock the results to see your code handles when the record is missing by your logic, etc...  You could simply sleep in your test for x seconds, to get a different time stamp.  I would watch though that depending on time stamps may have issues if you have to scale up to many servers.  If not, then you can do this, but as others have commented, it can be a risk.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out a good solution that apply to Eloquent only.

This is the same that is used for the Database Seeds.

We can add `Eloquent::unguard()` before instantiating the object in the test:

```
Eloquent::unguard();

Model::create(array('created_at' => '2014-12-17'));
```

So we can manually set the `created_at` field of the model, without exposing it to "everybody" who use the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon::setTestNow($now) for mocking now time

```
foreach ($list as $index => $test) {
    Carbon::setTestNow(now()->addDays($index + 1));
    // functionCreateModel();
}
```